# White Space on Mobile Site

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

This is my first time when I create a mobile site, it is still under construction for testing purpose. I have seen the white space on the right side of the mobile. My mobile has a resolution of 360*640px. Can someone please check my site through mobile and let me know where the problem was happening. Also the site was not showing responsive MENU which is before the logo. Everything was working fine on Firefox web developer add-on but in actual view, there was an issue.

I have seen my mobile through **Opera Mini** because i am using Nokia 5233.

Website - http://bit.ly/1bD6EhX

Comment: I’ve checked it with iPhone 3G and 4S. The problem appeared in horizontal view with 3G, the vertical one was OK. No problem with 4S.

Comment: @Melebius - Yes, i am working on horizontal view. Through which browser you have checked the site ?

Comment: The default one, Safari, in both cases.

Comment: Usually related to overflow: hidden not being handled properly by some mobile browsers.

Comment: @shawn: I have seen through another default mobile browser and now there menu was showing which opera mini not showing. However the right side white space is left there.